# Are you the best it's ever gonna get for her? (meaning)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Are you the best it's ever gonna get for her?

Can you break it down for me please?, the meaning and other possible usages. thanks

Comment: Are you (is your relationship with her) the best it is ever going to get for her (the best situation she can ever hope to be in)?

Answer (score -2):

Are you the best it's ever gonna get for her?

> - it's: here refer to her.
> - ever: refer to the entire life of the person.
> - gonna get: going to get.

I hope this may help you.